# Textbox equal to any other Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want it so that if any of my TextBoxes in line 2 has the same text as any other TextBox in line 2, they both get the background color red. Here's what I've done so far:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && c.Name.StartsWith("textBox2"))
        {
            ((TextBox)c).TextChanged += textBox_TC;
        }
    }
}

private void textBox_TC(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;           
    if(textBox.Text == textBox.Text && textBox.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}
```

Instead of having if textBox.Text == textBox.Text. I want it to be something like if textBox.Text == anyother.textBox.Text with a name that starts with textBox2.
Is that possible or do I have to go about this some other way?

Comment: How many of these `textBox2`s do you have?

Comment: 9, I'm making a sudoku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start building a `List<TextBox>` with the textbox having the same starting name

```
List<TextBox> box2;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Using LINQ to extract all the controls of type TextBox 
    // having a name starting with the characters textBox2 
    // BE AWARE - Is case sensitive -
    box2 = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                        .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("textBox2")).ToList();

    // Set to each textbox in the list the event handler
    foreach(TextBox t in box2)
        t.TextChanged += textBox_TC;

}
```

Now in your TextChanged event you could write

```
private void textBox_TC(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if(textBox.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        // Check if Any text box has the same text has the one 
        // firing the event (excluding the firing textbox itself)
        bool sameText = box2.Any(x => x.Text == textBox.Text && 
                                     !x.Equals(textBox));

        // Got one textbox with the same text?
        if(sameText) 
           textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment below, you could ensure the resetting of the background color in this way

WARNING NOT TESTED: Just a trace to follow.

```
private void textBox_TC(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if(textBox.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        foreach(TextBox t in box2)
            t.BackColor = Color.White;

        // Get all textboxes with the same text 
        var sameText = box2.Where(x => x.Text == textBox.Text);
        if(sameText.Count() > 1) 
        {
            foreach(TextBox t in sameText)
                t.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    else if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and I'm getting an error here "x.Name.StartsWith("textbox2").ToList();". Should there be something in front of  ".Where"? I haven't seen that code before.

Comment: I have forgotten a parenthesys in the first draft

Comment: This will only style the TextBox that fired the event, I think OP wants the matched one too.

Comment: @Crowcoder That was my intention from the start but it doesn't matter that much

Comment: @Crowcoder this would be a little more complicated. Mainly because you need to reset all the background colors in case of no more matching (Suppose you have two textbox colored in red and then you backspace in one of them, when the TextChanged fires you need to recheck everything to remove the backcolor)

Comment: @Steve ...which is why I mention it. This does not satisfy the requirements as originally stated, but OP is happy so it is moot now.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you this after so long but when one textbox is equal to another, one textbox gets the red background. But when I remove the number from the one that didn't get the red background the one other one still remains red. I tried putting in else if (sameText == false) textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; but it didn't help and I have no idea what to do. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well in this case you need to add a loop that resets every box2 color to its White default, then, instead of Any use Where. This returns an IEnumerable<TextBox> and if you have more than 1 Count paint the elements with the desidered background

Comment: Can't use Count>1 because "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'". I tried doing IEnumerable<TextBox> sameText = box2.Where(x => x.Text == textBox.Text); which would put all the textboxes that are equal to each other in sameText and then make them red but that didn't work at all. If you could help me a little bit more I'd be so happy.

Comment: My fault it is _if(sameText.Count() > 1)_